# When I installed angular2-image-gallery package it throws error in node-module's file imports rxjs/internal/Subscription

Tags: angular5, npm-install, node-modules, rxjs5

[Please have look on attached image for better idea. Click on this link to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLzqt.png)

I took the reference to create my image gallery from following the link - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-image-gallery

Steps I executed.

1. Clear the cache & removed node_modules
2. Installed angular2-Image-Gallery package and try to run app throws above error

Please help!

Comment: Provide more information about the error, where it take place, and sample of your code that throw the error.

Comment: The error occurs when I build the App. and it took place inside node-module's file.

Comment: I have attached error image link

Answer (score 0):

You should install rxjs

npm install --save rxjs-compat@6